# how to update data in sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, updates

I have a problem in the database program please guide me.
I created a database manually and copied it to the assets folder and runs all parts of my program, but I do not know how to complete the update and when it runs, there is no problem, but it does not update.

This is my database code:

```
package com.alireza.fitnessclub;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private Context main_context;
private static String DB_PATH;
private static int DB_VERSION = 3;
private static final String DB_NAME = "fitness_db.db";
private static final String DB_TBL_INFO = "personal";
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    main_context = context;
    DB_PATH = context.getCacheDir().getPath() + "/" + DB_NAME;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


private boolean dbExists() {
    File f = new File(DB_PATH);
    if (f.exists())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
private boolean copyDB() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH);
        InputStream in = main_context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, ch);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do nothing
        return false;
    }
}

public void open() {
    if (dbExists()) {
        try {
            File temp = new File(DB_PATH);
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(temp.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            //do nothing
        }

    } else {
        if (copyDB())
            open();

    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    db.close();
}



public boolean setFavoritState(int id, int state) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("fav_flag", state);
    long result = db.update(DB_TBL_INFO, cv, "id = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    if (result < 1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
public int getFavoritState(int id) {
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TBL_INFO + " WHERE id = '" + id + "'", null);
    result.moveToFirst();
    return (Integer.parseInt(result.getString(18)));
}

public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getTableData() {
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TBL_INFO, null);
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> all_data = new ArrayList<>();
    while (result.moveToNext()) {
        HashMap<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<>();
        temp.put("id", result.getString(0));
        temp.put("name", result.getString(1));
        temp.put("family", result.getString(2));
        temp.put("photo",result.getString(16));
        temp.put("date", result.getString(17));

        if (result.getString(18).equals("1"))
        {
            temp.put("fav_flag", R.drawable.fav);
        }
        else
        {
            temp.put("fav_flag", R.drawable.fav_click);
        }

        all_data.add(temp);

    }
    return all_data;
}

public HashMap<String, Object> getData(String id) {
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TBL_INFO + " WHERE id = '" + id + "' ", null);
    result.moveToFirst();
    HashMap<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<>();
    temp.put("id", result.getString(0));
    temp.put("name", result.getString(1));
    temp.put("family", result.getString(2));
    temp.put("age", result.getString(3));
    temp.put("weight", result.getString(4));
    temp.put("height", result.getString(5));
    temp.put("arm", result.getString(6));
    temp.put("shoulder", result.getString(7));
    temp.put("chest", result.getString(8));
    temp.put("abdomen", result.getString(9));
    temp.put("glutes", result.getString(10));
    temp.put("femore", result.getString(11));
    temp.put("gas", result.getString(12));
    temp.put("phone", result.getString(13));
    temp.put("email", result.getString(14));
    temp.put("sex", result.getString(15));
    temp.put("photo", result.getString(16));
    temp.put("date", result.getString(17));

    if (result.getString(18).equals("1"))
    {
        temp.put("fav_flag", R.drawable.fav);
    }
    else
    {
        temp.put("fav_flag", R.drawable.fav_click);
    }
    temp.put("program", result.getString(19));

    return temp;
}

public void inserData(HashMap<String , Object> all_data)
{


    open();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", all_data.get("name").toString());
    cv.put("family",all_data.get("family").toString());
    cv.put("age", all_data.get("age").toString());
    cv.put("weight", all_data.get("weight").toString());
    cv.put("height", all_data.get("height").toString());
    cv.put("arm", all_data.get("arm").toString());
    cv.put("shoulder", all_data.get("shoulder").toString());
    cv.put("chest", all_data.get("chest").toString());
    cv.put("abdomen", all_data.get("abdomen").toString());
    cv.put("glutes", all_data.get("glutes").toString());
    cv.put("femore", all_data.get("femore").toString());
    cv.put("gas", all_data.get("gas").toString());
    cv.put("phone", all_data.get("phone").toString());
    cv.put("email", all_data.get("email").toString());
    cv.put("sex",all_data.get("sex").toString());
    cv.put("photo", all_data.get("photo").toString());
    cv.put("fav_flag",all_data.get("fav_flag").toString());
    db.insert(DB_TBL_INFO,null,cv);
    db.close();
}

public void updateData(HashMap<String , Object> all_data)
{
        open();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name", all_data.get("name").toString());
        cv.put("family", all_data.get("family").toString());
        cv.put("age", all_data.get("age").toString());
        cv.put("weight", all_data.get("weight").toString());
        cv.put("height", all_data.get("height").toString());
        cv.put("arm", all_data.get("arm").toString());
        cv.put("shoulder", all_data.get("shoulder").toString());
        cv.put("chest", all_data.get("chest").toString());
        cv.put("abdomen", all_data.get("abdomen").toString());
        cv.put("glutes", all_data.get("glutes").toString());
        cv.put("femore", all_data.get("femore").toString());
        cv.put("gas", all_data.get("gas").toString());
        cv.put("phone", all_data.get("phone").toString());
        cv.put("email", all_data.get("email").toString());

            db.update(DB_TBL_INFO, cv, "id =?",new String[]{all_data.get("id").toString()});
            db.close();

}
public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getTableOfsearch(String q)
{
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TBL_INFO + " WHERE " + q, null);
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> all_data = new ArrayList<>();
    while (result.moveToNext()) {
        HashMap<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<>();
        temp.put("id", result.getString(0));
        temp.put("name", result.getString(1));
        temp.put("family", result.getString(2));
        temp.put("date", result.getString(17));

        if (result.getString(18).equals("1"))
        {
            temp.put("fav_flag", R.drawable.fav);
        }
        else
        {
            temp.put("fav_flag", R.drawable.fav_click);
        }

        all_data.add(temp);

    }
    return all_data;
}

public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getTblFavoritPersonal() {
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TBL_INFO + " WHERE fav_flag ='0' ", null);
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> all_data = new ArrayList<>();
    while (result.moveToNext()) {
        HashMap<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<>();
        temp.put("id", result.getString(0));
        temp.put("name", result.getString(1));
        temp.put("family", result.getString(2));
        temp.put("photo",result.getString(16));
        temp.put("date", result.getString(17));

        all_data.add(temp);

    }
    return all_data;
}

public void deleteData(String id)
{
    open();
    db.delete(DB_TBL_INFO,"id=?",new String[]{id});
    db.close();
}


}
```

This is an activity where I used the update:

```
package com.alireza.fitnessclub;

import android.Manifest; 
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Profile_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DatabaseHandler db;
private HashMap<String, Object> personals;
private TextView name, family, age, weight, height, arm, shoulder, chest, abdomen, glutes, femore, gast, date, phone, email , gender;
EditText et_name, et_family, et_age, et_weight, et_height, et_arm, et_shoulder, et_chest, et_abdomen, et_glutes, et_femore, et_gast, et_date, et_phone, et_email;
private ImageView fav , pro_img1;
private ImageButton dial;
private String phone_num ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_activity);

    Toolbar tolbar= (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(tolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    db = new DatabaseHandler(getBaseContext());
    Bundle bData = getIntent().getExtras();

    db.open();
    personals = db.getData(bData.getString("id"));

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_family);
    age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_age);
    weight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_weight);
    height = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_height);
    arm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_arm);
    shoulder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_shoulder);
    chest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_chest);
    abdomen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_abdomen);
    glutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_glutes);
    femore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_femore);
    gast = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_gast);
    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
    gender =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_gender);
    fav = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fav_img_btn);
    dial = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dial_img);
    pro_img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_img1);


    name.setText(personals.get("name").toString());
    family.setText(personals.get("family").toString());
    age.setText(personals.get("age").toString());
    weight.setText(personals.get("weight").toString());
    height.setText(personals.get("height").toString());
    arm.setText(personals.get("arm").toString());
    shoulder.setText(personals.get("shoulder").toString());
    chest.setText(personals.get("chest").toString());
    abdomen.setText(personals.get("abdomen").toString());
    glutes.setText(personals.get("glutes").toString());
    femore.setText(personals.get("femore").toString());
    gast.setText(personals.get("gas").toString());
    date.setText(personals.get("date").toString());
    gender.setText(personals.get("sex").toString());
    phone_num = personals.get("phone").toString();

    File imgfile = new File(personals.get("photo").toString());
    if (imgfile.exists()) {
        Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgfile.getAbsolutePath());
        pro_img1.setImageBitmap(mybitmap);
    } else {
        pro_img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.man);
    }

    fav.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(personals.get("fav_flag").toString()));

    db.close();
}

public void onImgFav(View v) {
    db.open();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(personals.get("id").toString());
    if (db.getFavoritState(id) == 0) {
        db.setFavoritState(id, 1);
        fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
    } else {
        db.setFavoritState(id, 0);
        fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_click);
    }
    db.close();

}
public void onEditClick(View v)
{

    AlertDialog.Builder loder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_activity , (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.edit_layout));

    et_name = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    et_family = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_family);
    et_age = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_age);
    et_weight = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_weight);
    et_height = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_height);
    et_arm = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_arm);
    et_shoulder = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_shoulder);
    et_chest = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_chest);
    et_abdomen = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_abdomen);
    et_glutes = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_glutes);
    et_femore = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_femore);
    et_gast = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_gast);
    et_phone = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_phone);
    et_email = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_email);

    et_name.setText(personals.get("name").toString());
    et_family.setText(personals.get("family").toString());
    et_age.setText(personals.get("age").toString());
    et_weight.setText(personals.get("weight").toString());
    et_height.setText(personals.get("height").toString());
    et_arm.setText(personals.get("arm").toString());
    et_shoulder.setText(personals.get("shoulder").toString());
    et_chest.setText(personals.get("chest").toString());
    et_abdomen.setText(personals.get("abdomen").toString());
    et_glutes.setText(personals.get("glutes").toString());
    et_femore.setText(personals.get("femore").toString());
    et_gast.setText(personals.get("gas").toString());
    et_phone.setText(personals.get("phone").toString());
    et_email.setText(personals.get("email").toString());


    loder.setView(layout);
    loder.setCancelable(false);
    loder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {

                db.open();
                HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

                data.put("name", et_name.getText().toString());
                data.put("family", et_family.getText().toString());
                data.put("age", et_age.getText().toString());
                data.put("weight", et_weight.getText().toString());
                data.put("height", et_height.getText().toString());
                data.put("arm", et_arm.getText().toString());
                data.put("shoulder", et_shoulder.getText().toString());
                data.put("chest", et_chest.getText().toString());
                data.put("abdomen", et_abdomen.getText().toString());
                data.put("glutes", et_glutes.getText().toString());
                data.put("femore", et_femore.getText().toString());
                data.put("gas", et_gast.getText().toString());
                data.put("phone", et_phone.getText().toString());
                data.put("email", et_email.getText().toString());

                db.updateData(data);
                db.close();


        }
    });
    loder.setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    loder.create();
    loder.show();


}


public void onDialClick(View v) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setCancelable(true);
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.call);
    alert.setTitle("Dial");
    alert.setMessage( phone_num + " ?");
    alert.setPositiveButton("call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0" + phone_num));
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();


}
public void onSmsClick(View v)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setCancelable(true);
    alert.setTitle("SMS");
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.massag);
    alert.setMessage( phone_num + " ?");
    alert.setPositiveButton("SMS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            String smsText = "";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:0" + phone_num);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsText);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
}
```

Comment: First thing I'd do is add a breakpoint at `db.update(DB_TBL_INFO, cv, "id =?",new String[]{all_data.get("id").toString()});` in the `updateData` method and the run in debug mode. If it doesn't reach breakpoint it's not getting to the `updateData` method. Else you want to see that the **id** member of all_data is a valid/expected id (most likely error is that it is not).

Comment: You could also make the line at the breakpoint `int updateresult = db.update(DB_TBL_INFO, cv, "id =?",new String[]{all_data.get("id").toString()});` and then when at breakpoint, place cursor at `db.close()` and then click run to cursor. You'd be expecting `updateresult` to not be 0 as it indicates the rows affected by the update. 0 would most likely mean that the id does not exist.

Comment: I can't recall if it's an issue with longs (certainly is with doubles) but you might want to use the `getLong` method rather then the `getString` method whenever you retrieve the id from a cursor. e.g. instead of `temp.put("id", result.getString(0));` use `temp.put"id",result.getLong(0).toString());`. Personally I'd also change the **id** member to be a long rather than a string.

Comment: What can I do? I'm going to get the update id in the string array?

Comment: First follow the steps above re adding the breakpoints so you split the potential areas of failure and find out if there were any updates. If there were none then it's likely that the id that you're getting is not an id in the table.

Comment: The message is given when I debug the program :08-07 21:04:17.231 31867-31867/com.alireza.fitnessclub E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.alireza.fitnessclub, PID: 31867
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: @MikeT Problem of updating was solved. Thank you for your guidance :  Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TBL_INFO, null);
        result.moveToFirst();

        db.update(DB_TBL_INFO,cv,"id=?",new String[]{result.getString(0)});